# Get text of HTML tags without text of inner child tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Example:

Sometimes the HTML is:

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
        this is the text i do NOT want
    </div>
    this is the text i want here
</div>
```

Other times it's just:

```
<div id="1">
    this is the text i want here
</div>
```

I want to get only the text in the one tag, and ignore all other child tags. If I run the `.text` property, I get both.

Comment: Why don't you get the text of outer and replace all texts of its direct children?

Comment: @tuananh How would you know what to replace if the text of a direct child is also part of a string that is in the parent as in `<div>a b c<div>b</div>e f</div>` ?

Comment: Is the text guaranteed to follow any and all inner child tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated** to use a more generic method (see edit history for original answer):

You can extract child elements of the outer div by testing whether they are instances of [`NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '''<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
        this is the text i do NOT want
    </div>
    this is the text i want here
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)    
outer = soup.div
inner_text = [element for element in outer if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]
```

This results in a list of strings contained in the outer div element.

```
>>> inner_text
[u'\n', u'\n    this is the text i want here\n']
>>> ''.join(inner_text)
u'\n\n    this is the text i want here\n'
```

For your second example:

```
html = '''<div id="1">
    this is the text i want here
</div>'''
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html)    
outer = soup2.div
inner_text = [element for element in outer if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]

>>> inner_text
[u'\n    this is the text i want here\n']
```

This will also work for other cases such as the outer div's text element being present before any child tags, between child tags, multiple text elements, or not present at all.

Comment: I don't always know if it will have an inner tag or not.

Comment: The first method doesn't work if the text happens to be before the inner `<div>`, or before and after. And if the text is before, the second version gives the wrong text.

Comment: And since the inner `<div>` is optional, the first won't work?

Comment: @Anthon: yes, my original answer was based solely on the OP's example. I've updated the answer with a generic solution.

Comment: @mhawke the OP later extended the examples and stated those were representative. I would not have commented on the possible problems with your original solution if that had been clear from the start.

Comment: Your second old solution world work `list(soup.find('div', id='1').stripped_strings)[-1]`

Answer (score 15):

Another possible approach (I would make it in a function) :

```
def getText(parent):
    return ''.join(parent.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip()
```

`recursive=False` indicates that you want only direct children, not nested ones. And `text=True` indicates that you want only text nodes.

Usage example :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
        this is the text i do NOT want
    </div>
    this is the text i want here
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(getText(soup.div))
#this is the text i want here
```