# How to skip <span> with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is output of my code

```
<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>item name goes here</h1>
```

I want to get item name only, without "details about" part.

My Python code the selects the certain div id is

```
for content in soup.select('#itemTitle'):
    print(content.text)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) [clear()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#clear) or [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract).
According to the documentation:

> Tag.decompose() removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents
>
> Tag.clear() removes the contents of a tag
>
> PageElement.extract() removes a tag or string from the tree. It returns the tag or string that was extracted

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>item name goes here</h1>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for content in soup.select('#itemTitle'):
    content.span.decompose()
    print(content.text)
```

Output:

```
  item name goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is inspired by this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159020/get-text-of-html-tags-without-text-of-inner-child-tags).

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

data = '''
<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>item name goes here</h1>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
inner_text = [element for element in soup.h1 if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]
print(inner_text)
```

Output:

```
['item name goes here']
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html= """<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>item name goes here</h1>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

text = soup.find('h1', attrs={"id":"itemTitle"}).text
span = soup.find('span', attrs={"class":"g-hdn"}).text

final_text = text[len(span):]

print(final_text)
```

This results in:

```
item name goes here
```

Comment: Worked :)
Simple solution and working. Thank you so much.

Comment: thanks, I think there are some other solutions that are better, but this should be the easiest if the span always comes first in the content you are scraping

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name">
<span class="g-hdn">Details about  </span>
item name goes here</h1>""")  
print(soup.find('h1', {'class': 'it-ttl'}).contents[-1].strip())
```