# BeautifulSoup find - exclude nested tag from block of interest

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nested

I have a scraper that looks for pricing on particular product pages. I'm only interested in the current price - whether the product is on sale or not.

I store the identifying tags like this in a JSON file:

```
{
    "some_ecommerce_site" : {
        "product_name" : ["span", "data-test", "product-name"],
        "breadcrumb" : ["div", "class", "breadcrumbs"],
        "sale_price" : ["span", "data-test", "sale-price"],
        "regular_price" : ["span", "data-test", "product-price"]
    },
}
```

And have these functions to select current price and clean up the price text:

```
def get_pricing(rpi, spi):
    sale_price = self.soup_object.find(spi[0], {spi[1] : spi[2]})
    regular_price = self.soup_object.find(rpi[0], {rpi[1] : rpi[2]})

    return sale_price if sale_price else regular_price

def get_text(obj):
    return re.sub(r'\s\s+', '', obj.text.strip()).encode('utf-8')
```

Which are called by:

```
def get_ids(name_of_ecommerce_site):
    with open('site_identifiers.json') as j:
        return json.load(j)[name_of_ecommerce_site]

def get_data():
    rpi = self.site_ids['regular_price']
    spi = self.site_ids['sale_price']

    product_price = self.get_text( self.get_pricing(rpi, spi) )
```

This works for all but one site so far because their pricing is formatted like so:

```
<div class="product-price">
    <h3>
    £15.00
        <span class="price-standard">
            £35.00
        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

So what `product_price` returns is "£15£35" instead of the desired "£15".

Is there a simple way to exclude the nested `<span>` which won't break for the working sites?

I thought a solution would be to get a list and select index 0, but checking the tag's contents, that won't work as it's a single item in the list:

```
>> print(type(regular_price))
>> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 
>> print(regular_price.contents)
>> [u'\n', <h3>\n\n\xa325.00\n\n<span class="price-standard">\n\n\xa341.00\n</span>\n</h3>, u'\n']
```

I've tried creating a list out of the result's NavigableString elements then filtering out the empty strings:

```
filter(None, [self.get_text(unicode(x)) for x in sale_price.find_all(text=True)])
```

This fixes that one case, but breaks a few of the others (since they often have the currency in a different tag than the value amount) - I get back "£".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the text without child element one.You can do like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString


html = """
<div class="product-price">
    <h3>
    £15.00
        <span class="price-standard">
            £35.00
        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
"""
bs = BeautifulSoup(html,"xml")
result = bs.find("div",{"class":"product-price"})
fr = [element for element in result.h3 if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]
print(fr[0])
```

> question may be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159020/get-text-of-html-tags-without-text-of-inner-child-tags/30159092)

Comment: I did actually come across this (and multiple similar) answers. The problem I have is that the element and nested tags aren't standard (different e-commerce sites do it differently), so I need something more general (so that it doesn't break the other cases).

Comment: @rong so can you add more examples , i may find a solution

Comment: there was so much variance that I approached the problem completely differently. I use `soup.find_all(string=True)` to find all string containing tags and then use regex patterns to match the attribute values of parent tags (e.g. `'.*product price.*'`) to determine if the text is of interest, then just stick it into a list (which I post-process). But you did answer my question =) thanks