# Exclusion of span with BS4 - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to exclude (not extract) the info contained in a span.
Here's the HTML:

```
<li><span>Type:</span> Cardiac Ultrasound</li>
```

And here's my code:

```
item_description_infos = listing_soup.find(class_='item_description').find_all('li')
for description_el in item_description_infos: 
        description_elements = description_el.find('span')
        for el in description_elements: 
            curr_el = {}
            key = el.replace(':', '')
            print(el)
            print(description_el.text.replace(' ', ''))
```

Where listing soup is basically the whole page (in my example the HTML)
When I do that I get:

```
Type:
Type: CardiacUltrasound
```

As you can see. For some extraordinary reason :P, the `span` isn't affected by my `replace()` method even-though `.text` yields a `str`

EDIT: Sorry. My objective is to create a bunch of `dictionnaries` where the `key` is the `span` and the `value` what comes after it.

Comment: What about `description_el.find(text=True)`?

Comment: That's so weird... doing that I only get the span (I mean the text from the span). Not the remaining text. In my example "Type:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Be careful about "creating a bunch of dictionaries", as dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. But you could have a list of dictionaries, which in that case, won't matter (well still matters within each individual dictionary).

**Option 1:**

Use `.next_sibling()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="item_description">
<li><span>Type:</span> Cardiac Ultrasound</li></div>'''

listing_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

item_description_infos = listing_soup.find(class_='item_description').find_all('li')
for description_el in item_description_infos: 
    k = description_el.find('span').text.replace(':', '')
    v = description_el.find('span').next_sibling.strip()
    
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

**Option 2:**

Just get the text from `description_el`, the `.split(':')`. Then you got the 2 elements you want (if I'm reading your question correctly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="item_description">
<li><span>Type:</span> Cardiac Ultrasound</li></div>'''

listing_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

item_description_infos = listing_soup.find(class_='item_description').find_all('li')
for description_el in item_description_infos: 
    descText = description_el.text.split(':', 1)
    k = descText[0].strip()
    v = descText[-1].strip()
    
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

**Option 3:**

Get the `<span>` text. Remove it. Then get the remaining text in the `<li>`. Although since you're not wanting to extract, might not be useful to you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="item_description">
<li><span>Type:</span> Cardiac Ultrasound</li></div>'''

listing_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

item_description_infos = listing_soup.find(class_='item_description').find_all('li')
for description_el in item_description_infos: 
    k = description_el.find('span').text.replace(':','')
    description_el.find('span').extract()
    v = description_el.text.strip()
    
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

**Output:**

```
Type
Cardiac Ultrasound
```

Comment: That's sort of a different solution to my "replace" function. It's actually a better one that mine but there's still a problem.. Here's what I get `['Type:\xa0Cardiac Ultrasound']`. It's as if the `text` method doesn't yield a `str`... and I've checked... yes it is.

Comment: @Ardzii, just specify all chars you need to clean in `.strip()` call. E.g. `s.strip(" :\xa0")`

Comment: @Ardzii, check my solution Option 1. See if that works correctly.

Comment: Ya that's probably the best/most robust.

Answer (score 1):

To extract text of tag excluding content of child tags you can use method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159092/10824407) answer. Generally you just need to iterate over `<li>` tags and get text from ones which contains child `<span>`.

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = """<html><body>
<li><span>Key1:</span> Value1</li>
<li><span>Key2:</span> Value2</li>
<li><NoKeyValue</li>
<li><span>Key3:</span> Value3</li>
<li><span>Key4:</span> Value4</li>
</body></html>"""

result = {}
for li in BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find_all("li"):
    span = li.find("span")
    if span:
        result[span.text.strip(" :")] = \
            "".join(e for e in li if isinstance(e, NavigableString)).strip()
```